# Python 3 global variable unexpectedly stops working in the middle of execution throwing "... is not defined" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, undefined, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

As I mentioned in the question, I have created a SublimeText plugin which is attempting to save file 6 seconds from it's first keystroke intended for editing the file.

This is the code I have come up with:

```
import time,sublime,calendar,datetime,sublime_plugin

class SaveOnModifiedListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    wasStamp = None
    nowStamp = None
    def on_modified(self, view):
        global wasStamp
        global nowStamp
        if wasStamp is None: wasStamp = int(time.time())
        nowStamp = int(time.time())
        print(nowStamp - wasStamp)
        if (nowStamp - wasStamp) >= 6:
            view.run_command("save")
            wasStamp = None
```

The error it's throwing makes it seem there's no error on Sublime side but Python is throwing this error of `wasStamp is not defined` on this line `if wasStamp is None: wasStamp = int(time.time())` because it thinks there's some syntax issue, which there isn't.

Anyone can help find the actual reason of this error and fix it ?

Comment: There is no global variable called `wasStamp`. Did you mean the one in the class scope? It should probably be an instance variable, anyway.

Comment: In a class you don't access class variables as a global. You can either access them as an instance variable `self.wasStamp`, or static with the class name: `SaveOnModifiedListener.wasStamp` depending on what behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: Yes that same variable I want to use and modify frequently as I wish..

Comment: I suspect you had a global variable when you were first testing it, but then when you tried using the code later you didn't define the global variable.

Comment: No I think I mixed up some concepts of class variable vs global variable

Answer (score 0):

```
class foo():
   x = 1

   def bar(self, val):
       global x
       x = val
       print(f"bar - Global x = {x}")
       print(f"bar - Self.x = {self.x}")

   def baz(self):
       print(f"baz - Global x = {x}")
       print(f"baz - Self.x = {self.x}")

f = foo()
f.bar(10)
f.baz()
print(f"X outside class = {x}")
```

```
python3 x.py
bar - Global x = 10
bar - Self.x = 1
baz - Global x = 10
baz - Self.x = 1
X outside class = 10
```

I hope this clarifies

Comment: I don't believe the original intent the OP was going for was to use `global` in the end. It's a matter of the proper use of class variables. Perhaps explaining why `global` is not what is needed here and instead show an example on how to use `class` variables instead would be closer to addressing the issue?